# How to apply a VBA macro to all files in a directory?

Tags: bash, vba, ms-word

I have a sub-directory with ~1000 Word Documents I'd like to apply the following macro to style hyperlinks to each of them, but I can't really open each of them to run the script. Is there any way I can set it to apply to every document in the directory? Could I call it from a bash script?

```
Sub FormatLinks()
    Dim H As Hyperlink

    For Each H In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        H.Range.Select                                      ' (A)
        Selection.ClearFormatting                           ' (B)

        H.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Hyperlink")  ' (C)
    Next H
End Sub
```

Comment: Temporarily add it to document_open. & then using cmd batch script or otherwise, open all the word documents one by one. Also, add a document close call in the document_open. AFAIK, when you open word, without any document as argument, document_open macro will not be called. Thus you may be able to delete it after you are done. You may want to define a better exit condition.

Comment: Alternately, & in better way, you can use (in a separate vbs file) createobject function to create msword document object. then open these files one by one, apply these formatting changes & close the files after saving them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from Filter, a program that filters stdin to stdout. This part here is from run a command line specifed script on each line in a file. `Dir /b` gives you a list of files.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    RawScript = Arg(1)
    'Remove ^ from quoting command line and replace : with vbcrlf so get line number if error
    Script = Replace(RawScript, "^", "")
    Script = Replace(Script, "'", chr(34))
    Script = Replace(Script, ":", vbcrlf)
    'Building the script with predefined statements and the user's code
    Script = "Dim gU" & vbcrlf & "Dim gdU" & vbcrlf & "Set gdU = CreateObject(" & chr(34) & "Scripting.Dictionary" & chr(34) & ")" & vbcrlf & "Function UF(L, LC)" & vbcrlf & "Set greU = New RegExp" & vbcrlf & "On Error Resume Next" & vbcrlf & Script & vbcrlf & "End Function" & vbcrlf

    'Testing the script for syntax errors
    On Error Resume Next
    set ScriptControl1 = wscript.createObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl",SC)
        With ScriptControl1
            .Language = "VBScript"
            .UseSafeSubset = False
            .AllowUI = True
        .AddCode Script
    End With
    With ScriptControl1.Error
        If .number <> 0 then
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(1)
            Outp.WriteLine "User function syntax error"
            Outp.WriteLine "=========================="
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(1)
            Outp.Write NumberScript(Script)
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(2)
            Outp.WriteLine "Error " & .number & " " & .description
            Outp.WriteLine "Line " & .line & " " & "Col " & .column
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ExecuteGlobal(Script)

    'Remove the first line as the parameters are the first line
    'Line=Inp.readline  
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        LineCount = Inp.Line 

        temp = UF(Line, LineCount)
        If err.number <> 0 then 
            outp.writeline ""
            outp.writeline ""
            outp.writeline "User function runtime error"
            outp.writeline "==========================="
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(1)
            Outp.Write NumberScript(Script)
            Outp.WriteBlankLines(2)
            Outp.WriteLine "Error " & err.number & " " & err.description
            Outp.WriteLine "Source " & err.source

            Outp.WriteLine "Line number and column not available for runtime errors"
            wscript.quit
        End If
        outp.writeline temp
    Loop
```

**General Use**

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command

Vbs

filter vbs "text of a vbs script"
filter vb "text of a vbs script"
```

Use colons to seperate statements and lines. Use single quotes in place of double quotes, if you need a single quote use chr(39). Escape brackets and ampersand with the ^ character. If you need a caret use chr(136).

The function is called UF (for UserFunction). It has two parameters, L which contains the current line and LC which contains the linecount. Set the results of the script to UF. See example.

There are three global objects available. An undeclared global variable gU to maintain state. Use it as an array if you need more than one variable. A Dictionary object gdU for saving and accessing previous lines. And a RegExp object greU ready for use.

**Example**

This vbs script inserts the line number and sets the line to the function UF which Filter prints.

```
filter vbs "uf=LC ^& ' ' ^& L"<"%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This is how it looks in memory

```
Dim gU
Set gdU = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set greU = New RegExp

Function UF(L, LC)

---from command line---
uf=LC & " " & L
---end from command line---

End Function
```

If there is a syntax error Filter will display debugging details.

## User function syntax error

```
1 Dim gU
2 Dim gdU
3 Set greU = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
4 Function UF(L, LC)
5 On Error Resume Next
6 uf=LC dim & " " & L
7 End Function

Error 1025 Expected end of statement
Line 6 Col 6
```

## User function runtime error

```
1 Dim gU
2 Dim gdU
3 Set greU = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
4 Function UF(L, LC)
5 On Error Resume Next
6 uf=LC/0 & " " & L
7 End Function

Error 11 Division by zero
Source Microsoft VBScript runtime error
Line number and column not available for runtime errors
```

**Other examples**

Reverse each line

```
filter vbs "uf=StrReverse^(L^)"<"%systemroot%\win.ini"
```